# animating the jquery dailogue from top left corner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi i want to toggle jquery dailogue from top left corner.
here is the code iam using for dailogue.

```
 function showCityPopUp(id,msgTitle){


    var  dialog=$('#'+id)  
      .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
  /*  show: "blind",
    hide: "explode",*/
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: true, 
    hide: 'fade',
    modal:true,
    width: 600,
    title: msgTitle,
    position:[404,288],

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missed close bracket

```
function showCityPopUp(id, msgTitle) {


    var dialog = $('#' + id)
        .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        /*  show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",*/
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        title: msgTitle,
        position: [404, 288],

    });
}
```